# Can CSS be used in a VB WinForms Application?

Tags: css, vb.net

Can we use css formatting in a vb application to give some enhancement? Examples would be changing the font color and or background?

Are there any other way to customize a (VB)desktop application?

Comment: Do you mean for web applications? The question is vague.

Comment: Indeed the question seems a bit vague, but I assume he is talking about an application that is not using a webbrowser to show an interface. Otherwise his question would be weird, since it's generally known a website can use css.

Answer (score 0):

Css is being used on websites, unless your vb app is running in a webbrowser you can't use css,  or it won't have effect.

Answer (score 0):

you can only apply css in web applications not window forms.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use CSS but in web applications.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot use CSS to define the style for a Windows Forms app.

**Yes** you can use CSS, but you need to write the parser yourself, and apply the results yourself also.